# zclip copy text to clipboard not working

Tags: jquery, copy, clipboard, zclip

I have this in `.jade`:

```
.col-md-9
    h4#enquiry-details Enquiry Details
.col-md-1
    a#copy-enquiry(href='#') Copy
```

Then in my `javascript`:

```
$(document).ready(          
    function() {
        $('a#copy-enquiry').zclip({
            path:'/javascripts/ZeroClipboard.swf',
            copy:$('h4#enquiry-details').text(),
         });
     }
);
```

I have included the `jquery` and `jquery.zclip.js` script in my header.

Somehow the copy to clipboard still not working. Any ideas?